# package did not get built

Tags: catkin-make, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ros indigo and trying to run the launch file or the node cpp file in [this github source](https://github.com/ros-drivers/kvh_drivers/tree/Indigo) I downloaded the file and moved the DSP-3000 folder into my `~/catkin_ws/src` directory. Then, in my `catkin_ws`, I did `source devel/setup.bash` then `catkin_make`.

All my other packages that's in the `src` directory got build, but DSP-3000 did not seem to get build. I deleted `build/ devel/` and `catkin_make` again. in the build results, it show that only 3 packages were found, but in my src/ folder, there is DSP-3000 as well:

```
-- ~~  traversing 3 packages in topological order:

-- ~~  - beginner_tutorials

-- ~~  - camera_info_manager_py

-- ~~  - axis_camera
```

This is what I have in my `src/` directory:

```
~/catkin_ws/src$ ls
axis_camera  beginner_tutorials  camera_info_manager_py  CMakeLists.txt  DSP-3000
```

So, what is the reason that DSP-3000 not being build?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290675/package-did-not-get-built/) by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28560/kparikh/) on 2018-05-09**:
Maybe you need to adjust your cmakelists.txt file.

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-05-09**:
are you talking about something like this [link](https://answers.ros.org/question/234449/catkin_make-skips-new-package/?answer=234798#post-id-234798)?
If this is the case, what would be the reason that other packages does not need this step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The DSP-3000 package you linked to uses the old rosbuild build system which is not compatible with the current catkin build system. This is why catkin_make is not recognising it as a package.

There's a [guide for migrating packages from rosbuild to catkin here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild) that will help you to convert this and get it building.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-05-10**:
Thank you, turns out the master branch is catkinized.